# ExecuteNonQueryAsync closes form

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

I recently discovered C#'s `await` and `async` keywords and have been trying to use them in some of my projects. However, one of my forms started unexpected closing. I have been able to replicate the issue in the sample code below:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        (new Form1()).ShowDialog();
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```

This is a form that only contains a button whose `onClick` event is linked to `button1_Click`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Visible = false;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TestDb;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT NULL", conn))
            {
                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
        Visible = true;
    }
}
```

When I run this and click the button, I can step down to the `await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()` line, but then execution jumps to the `Main()` method and writes "Done" to the console before exiting. If I don't make the form invisible, if I call it using `Application.Show` instead of `ShowDialog()`, or if I use either `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().Wait()` or `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead of the `await` keyword, the button works as expected and the form doesn't close. What is causing the form to unexpectedly close?

Comment: You might want to wrap that call in a try...catch block and see if an exception is being thrown.

Comment: I've tried try...catch blocks in both the main method and the button click method, but neither catch anything.

Comment: Button1 probably closes the form as well. And since events cannot be awaited the form is closed before the call to the database has completed.

Comment: I don't think Button1 closes the form. If I comment out the `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` line, I can click the button and watch it print "Test" out as many times as I want without the form closing.

Comment: And if you make a synchronous call to `ExecuteNonQuery`, does it work?

Comment: Yes, it prints out "Test" and the form doesn't close

Comment: @JimMischel, exception will be thrown without `try .. catch` block. `await` will unwrap if task failed with exceptions

Comment: I think you want use `await` for opening connection too. `await conn.OpenAsync();`

Comment: In `Main` method start application with `Application.Run(new Form1());` It should correctly start message loop which will handle asynchronous code correctly.  With your current approach `await` in the `Button_Click` event will return execution back to the caller which in your case is `Main` method and execute next lines after `ShowDialog()` and will terminate application.

Comment: Why does the visibility of the form make any difference then?

Comment: What you mean by visibility? You displaying form in all cases.

Comment: If I removed the `Visible=false;` line, the program does not close the form. Instead it will continue execution in the click event method and print "Test" before waiting for me to click the button again.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem?

Comment: I have not. I can work around it by making the form visible, but I'm not sure why the original code doesn't work.